# Why is Akka HTTP Routing Catching My Exception?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

Given this code

```
def leaderboardPost(name: Option[String]): Route =
  post {
    logRequest("leaderboard", Logging.DebugLevel) {
      handleRejections(postBodyRejections) {
        entity(as[LeaderboardPostRequest]) { leaderboard =>
          try {
            complete(leaderboardCreate(Some(leaderboard.name), Some(leaderboard.kind)))
          } catch {
            case cause: DuplicateIDException =>
              logger.error(cause)
              complete(cause.response)
            case cause: UnknownKindException =>
              logger.warn(cause)
              complete(cause.response)
            case cause: Throwable =>
              logger.error(cause)
              complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, entity = s"Exception thrown from LeaderboardPost: ${cause.getMessage}"))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

when `leaderboardCreate` throws `UnknownKindException` the routing code catches it and transforms it to `Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.`

While I am looking at creating a custom ExceptionHandler, I don't understand why I need to. My code should catch it and return `complete(cause.response)` instead. How does Akka HTTP catch the exception before my code does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my understanding this happens because `leaderboardCreate` is not actually executed synchronously to the `complete` call as you might expect. The `complete` method returns a `StandardRoute` which extends from `Route` defines as:

```
type Route = RequestContext ⇒ Future[RouteResult]
```

In other words "route" is a function from a context to a `Future` (of `RouteResult`). And if you look at the `complete` definition, it is simply:

```
def complete(m: ⇒ ToResponseMarshallable): StandardRoute =
  StandardRoute(_.complete(m))
```

Note the `⇒` before `ToResponseMarshallable`. This is passing a parameter [by name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) which effectively turns it into a lazy evaluation.

In other words all your `try/catch` wraps is very small (and exception free) code of building the `StandardRoute` that captures your logic as a lazy value, but not the execution of the logic itself. That's why you need a [custom ExceptionHandler](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/exception-handling.html) which you (or rather Akka) can actually put into the chain of error handlers for the `Future` when it will be run.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks. The using the custom ExceptionHander solves the issue.

Comment: @EricKolotyluk, well, if this is the answer to your question, why not mark it as the Accepted one?